# Changing the diNovo Mini stick modes from Linux?

Tags: usb, logitech

If I plug in the diNovo Mini stick lsusb says

```
ID 046d:c71f Logitech, Inc. diNovo Mini Wireless Keyboard
ID 046d:c71e Logitech, Inc. 
ID 046d:0b07 Logitech, Inc.
```

If I keep the red button pressed when plugging in, I get

```
ID 046d:c709 Logitech, Inc. BT Mini-Receiver (HCI mode)
ID 046d:0b07 Logitech, Inc.
```

Now, if this used in a docking station, then the laptop is undocked/docked makes the stick revert from the second to the first. And, the first is useless to me. Is there a way to induce the stick to change to a BT stick while plugged in? I observe the `046d:0b07` device being present in both cases so perhaps that could be talked to.

Answer (score 1):

The utility is called `hid2hci` and it's in the `bluez` package you need to install anyways for Bluetooth. (On Arch, it's in `bluez-hid2hci`)

For other sticks the change is completely automatic. But this stick is not recognized by the relevant udev rule. So I did `sudo cp /lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules  /etc/udev/rules.d/` and then changed the logitech line:

```
KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[34bcf]", \
  RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p"
```

Note the `f` at the end of the first line, that's what was missing.

Comment: so, how is this used to solve your problem?